# what are these tiny beings?

Tags: the-witcher

In the fields crypt I saw some small dwarf like creatures. They are scared when I walk towards them. can I know who they are?
[image]

Comment: I don't play the Witcher myself, but isn't there some sort of feature where you can view all of the creatures you've encountered?

Comment: apparently I haven't found book or scroll to describe them so they are neither in glossary nor in characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Witcher Wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Crypt_in_the_fields) those are **"Bad" Griggs**

> The griggs are tiny humanoids which Geralt encounters in Murky Waters as part of the Small Problems quest. There appear to be at least two tribes of griggs: the so-called "good" tribe and and a "bad" tribe. The good tribe inhabits the area between the currently ruined bridge to the fields and the riverbank, while the "bad" tribe has taken up residence in one of the deeper chambers of the crypt in the fields.
>   Places Bad Griggs Santon
>   Even the good tribe seems to have a rather mischievous streak. It seems that these tiny creatures let their opinions on the local bridge construction be known through nightly vandalism, much to the consternation of the local mason, Harn and his son, Pat. They also exhibit a marked appreciation for alcohol.

**Griggs source:** [Witcher Wiki - Griggs](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Griggs)